# how to know the address of each variable, pointer, function, return address of function, etc. in a program?

Tags: c, memory-address

I want to check the address of each and every line of my code. I want to know:

- When variables are created, at what address?
- When functions are created, at what address?
- When a function returns, then at what address?

What I'm trying to do here?
Using dumpbin to get the information.

What do I expect?

```
fun main add:0x0000
var int i add:0x2496
var int j add:0x249A
```

A proper help with proper explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Lines of code don't have addresses, except in your editor. But you could execute your code in an emulator and inspect it after every instruction (that's going to be slow, though).

Comment: What OS? Note that in C not all variables have an address (those declared `register`, those kept entriely in registers, those optimized out of existence).

Comment: "Lines of code don't have addresses" -- Some people don't seem to know much about how computers or their toolchain work. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF: "The Line Number Table, which maps code locations to source code locations and vice versa"

Comment: It does become fuzzy with optimizations though

Comment: I think you're looking for `DUMPBIN /SYMBOLS`, explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you request is not a normal part of the object code produced by the compiler and generally cannot be completely obtained by inspection of the object code or the normal symbol table. Most of this information is not retained in the object code because the purpose of the object code is simply to make it possible to execute the program. Information about the origin of the object code (such as source lines that created it or names used in source) is simply unnecessary for execution.

Much of the information you request is provided in debugging information that is generated by the compiler when you request it, as is done with the `-g` switch to GCC. This debugging information is created in a variety of formats, depending on the compiler. It is certainly possible to inspect this information yourself or with various tools, but the mean for doing so will depend in detail on the compiler and other tools you are using. Doing it useful would require a good deal of study about the debugging information format.

Much of the debugging information can be examined through the use of a debugger, such as `gdb`. A debugger typically provides tools to examine the instructions associated with a particular line of source code or to find the memory allocated for an object.

However, the map from source code to instructions or data in an executing program can be extremely complicated. Some lines of source code may have vanished completely because the optimizer deduced they were unnecessary. As a simple example, consider:

```
b = a;
c = b;
d = c;
```

I would expect that there is no instruction anywhere in the program for `c = b;`; I would expect that the compiler simply moves `a` directly into `d` without the intervening steps, and it might even optimize that way, depending on circumstances.

Additionally, while handling an object, such as one of your variables, the compiler might generate code that sometimes has the object in a register and not at all in memory and that sometimes has the object in memory. It is even possible for an object to be partly in memory and partly in a register. (E.g., if an object is composed of eight bytes and the compiler runs out of register space needed to do some work, it might store four bytes of the object to the stack, use the newly available register briefly, and reload the bytes from the stack.)

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very vague. You don't mention a compiler, processor, or operating system, which might all affect this.

Also note that only things that are global in nature (like `static` variables and functions) can be expected to have absolute addresses.

Automatic variables ("ordinary" ones) will typically be created on the stack, and thus not have absolute addresses that you can know before the variable is in scope.

Lines of code certainly don't have addresses, in particular it doesn't have to be all sequential. For instance, a typical C `for` loop header is a single line of code at the source level:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
```

but it can generate assembly that is spread out, with some of it being after the loop's body and some before.

Also, there's no guarantee that a particular line of source code generates any particular amount of machine code, some might disappear due to optimization by the compiler, and of course for data declarations there's even less of a guarantee.

Comment: "Lines of code certainly don't have addresses" -- That's odd; the debugger certainly thinks so. "there's no guarantee that a particular line of source code generates any particular amount of machine code" -- irrelevant. What is relevant is that, if optimizing, lines of code can get interspersed or even disappear ... so, don't optimize if you want to track lines of code. P.S. "Your question is very vague" is a reason to close it, not to answer it.

Comment: @JimBalter I think it's not so simple, I tried to make it clearer how I meant. And there's always the chance of having the question improved from meta-criticising it, even in an answer.

Comment: "I think it's not so simple" -- It's certainly not so simple as "Lines of code certainly don't have addresses" -- that's shear ignorance. A good answer would talk about line tables that inform debuggers about where code is in memory.

Comment: Hello Sir, apologize for the inappropriate question. Actually I want to know the address of each function and its return address in case of recursive function so that I can trap when and where my function is getting called and from which function it is get called. Excatly I'm looking some kind of lookup table where function name is given and the address of it from where it is get called.